# Duplicate and customize secondary y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

This should be simple but I am getting some errors. I want to duplicate and then customize the labels of the secondary y axis.

First, this simple code should yield the following figure:

```
  ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis())
```

[image]

But I don't know why I get the following error (it works without the `scale_` arguments and I have ggplot2 version 2.2.1):

`Error in .Call(rhs, f) : first argument must be a string (of length 1) or native symbol reference`

Second, once the y axis is duplicated in right side, I would like to change the tick labels (20, 30, 40) for, let's say, ("a", "b", "c").

How can I fix that error and customize the tick labels of the secondary y axis?

Comment: A shot in the dark: Could you run library("lazyeval") before the rest of the codes?

Comment: I think you were right -see the comment below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first part of the code works well for me with the same version of ggplot2(2.2.1). In relation to your second question, using `sec_axis()` does the job. The first argument is the transformation formula `trans`, since you want to have the same scale but change just the labels then use `~ . * 1` e.g.:

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis()) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1, breaks = c(20,30,40), labels = c("a","b","c")))
```

[image]

Note: Be aware that the "transformation for secondary axes must be a formula".

Comment: Clear and quick, thanks. I answer myself the first question regarding the error. It seems there was something in the environment which caused an error when loading ggplot2 (`failed to assign NativeSymbolInfo for rhs since rhs is already defined in the ‘lazyeval’ namespace`) and therefore prevented me to do this kind of graph (I think it is related with the symbol €). To solve that I just cleared my enviroment before starting (`rm(list = ls())`)